# Form validation in Joomla with form rules doesn't work

Tags: jform, fields, validations

It will try to include new rules to validate the fields of a form and it does not work. I can not even get messages on the screen. Am I missing something in the code?

Here is my code:

```
    <form addrulepath="/administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/rules">
    <field 
        name="custom_price" 
        label="Price" 
        description="Type price" 
        type="text" 
        validate="CustomNumber"
        required="true"
        message="Custom validation messsage"
    />
    </form>
```

In the /rules directory I have included a file with the name "Custom", which includes:

```
class JFormRuleCustomNumber extends JFormRule
{
    public function test(SimpleXMLElement $element, $value, $group = null, JRegistry $input = null, JForm $form = null)
    {
        if ($value < 1) {
            $element->attributes()->message = 'The value ' . $value . ' is not valid because it is less than 1';
            return false;
        }

        if ($value > 1000) {
            $element->attributes()->message = 'The value ' . $value . ' is not valid because it is greater than 1000';
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Am I missing some code? Why do not you even access the file inside `/rules`? Please, if there is any other way to validate on the server side I would appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The filename must be lowercase and match the name of the rule (not including casing). So rename `Custom.php` to `customnumber.php`.

Setting the message through `$element->attributes()->message` doesn't work for me. `$element['message']` works. But the recommended way to handle validation error is to return an Exception:

```
if ($value < 1)
{
    return new UnexpectedValueException('The value ' . $value . ' is not valid because it is less than 1');
}
```